# How to Resolve Error 503 Service Unavailable In Bing Map API

Tags: java, bing-api, bing-maps

I am using Bing map API ([Bing Spatial Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701734.aspx)) reverse geocode in java

After calling that service more times i am getting error **503 Service Unavailable**

I just see my key Status Report

[image]

I Just read about error in [Bing Map API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701737.aspx) at last in that page

"The response may contain a 503 HTTP status error code when the number of pending geocode dataflow jobs is exceeded. The maximum number of pending geocode dataflow jobs that can be associated with a Bing Maps Key is 10."

I have only one Key.....

So Have you any Idea to resolve that Problem...???

Or Please Give Me Suggestion on that...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are exceeding the limits allowed for this service as outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585136.aspx

You should be able to continue to use the service after 24 hours or less.

If you need to be able to constantly reverse geocode data on the fly, then use the Bing Maps REST Location API. This will process one query at a time, but allows you to make as many requests as you need (within the limits of your account).

Comment: Yes, after 24 hours or less, it solved but now.....when i call second time service to getting job status...in there are give me pending status......!! for that i cant call third service(Download result)......!

Comment: You have to wait until the pending status changes. This can take anywhere from a few minutes to 24 hours.